# I receive an image and I need to cut it to create a PDF with it cut into the left half and cut into the right half, how do I do this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jspdf

I have a code with analysis of an image via artificial intelligence, and I need to print the PDF with all this analysis, the person's image is cut in the middle and this cut part is mirrored to form a mirrored face when printing the PDF.
The problem is that I tried to use Canva, but it doesn't work, even though the console shows me that the class works normally. Furthermore, the image is only processed when I click on the download pdf button, so I need this process to run while the pdf is rendered for printing.

A try to use this code

```js
var img = new Image();
   img.onload = function() {
       var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
       canvas.width = img.width;
       canvas.height = img.height / 2; // Cortar a imagem ao meio
       var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
       ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height / 2, 0, 0, img.width, img.height / 2);
       var imageDataCortada = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
       doc.addImage(imageDataCortada, 'JPEG', imageX + 65, imageY + 115, imgWidthHalf - 30,    imgHeightHalf - 30);
       doc.addImage(imageDataCortada, 'JPEG', imageX, imageY + 115, imgWidthHalf - 30, imgHeightHalf - 30);
       doc.addImage(imageDataCortada, 'JPEG', imageX + 130, imageY + 115, imgWidthHalf - 30,     imgHeightHalf - 30);
};
  img.src = imageData;
```

But my results is just an error like this

````
TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(CSSImageValue or HTMLCanvasElement or HTMLImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or ImageBitmap or OffscreenCanvas or SVGImageElement or VideoFrame)'.
    at img.onload (static/js/bundle.js:50196:15)```
````